# Padding left for a text in Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I want to make **a certain block of a text** (not a whole document) "have a left padding". I could say:

```
text_box "some text", :at => [200, 100]
```

But that's not I'm looking for because it specifies x and y as the paddings, whereas I want to specify only x.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
indent(10, 15) do # left and right padding
  text "Some text"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it right now, but you can try something like this:

```
text_box "some text", :at => [200, cursor]
```

Where cursor is a method which returns the `cursor` y position.

I hope it helps.